# NEAT system failed to grow and thus find result

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I implemented NEAT system according to official research paper, but I make mistake somewhere.

I decided to test my system on traditional XOR network problem which requires at least one hidden neuron. My NEAT system simply not add new neuron. To be clear, sometimes, system found result (with around 2-3 neurons in hidden layers) but after really long time (thousands of generations with generation size 50 and specie count 10).

That's not good. What can possibly cause this behaviour? I think it's because innovations are lost so specie subsystem maybe not works correctly ...

EDIT:

```
generation size 50
mutate rate 80%
elitism
new neuron rate 3%
new connection rate 5%
no stolen babies (all species has same number of children)
specie count 10
mating between species 0%
```

Comment: Without seeing the code it is impossible to identify the mistake. However, if you are sure that you did it according to the paper, look for programming errors. Or get some other implementation and compare it. There is a [NEAT users page](https://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html).

Comment: Thank you for response, I can't post code because it's closed for now. I'm actively looking for errors, I posted this question because maybe someone can give me some pointer to module where problem has (potential) roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a example code, you can find it on my github: https://github.com/Lucas001/NEAT-for-autonomous-car.

But, trying to answer your question, what is your rate to add a neuron?

You can also look for help in a book called AI Techniques for Programming. The author uses c++ code to implement NEAT algorithm, while in my code it is in JAVA.